# solving linear program with rank constraint?

Tags: linear-programming, nonlinear-optimization

I have a linear program where the variables are n vectors.  Now I'd like to impose an extra constraint that k (k<=n) of the n vectors are linearly independent, or the matrix with the n vectors as rows has rank k.  It seems to me that this constraint destroys the linearity.  Is there any existing theory dealing with this kind of problem?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "destroys the linearity"?

Comment: I mean there's no way to represent it as a linear program any more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $k = 1$. Then all your vectors are multiples of the same vector. Number them $v_0,\ldots,v_n$. Add the constraints $v_{00} = 1$ and $v_{i0} = v_{0i}$. The rank constraint implies that $v_{ij}/v_{i0} = v_{0j}/v_{00}$ and so $v_{ij} = v_{i0} v_{0j} = v_{i0} v_{j0}$. Put $x_i = v_{i0}$, so that . We thus have a [quadratically constrained quadratic program](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratically_constrained_quadratic_program), which is NP-hard to optimize. The reason is that we can simulate zero/one integer programming by adding the constraint $x_i^2 = x_i$.